# Peers often report unknown top blocks. How can I find more reliable peers?

Tags: hard-fork, synchronization, nodes, daemon

The daemon regularly reports top blocks that are years in the past.

For example (IP addresses are anonymized):

```
2016-Oct-23 06:13:27.789171 [P2P2][123.45.67.89:18080 OUT] SYNCHRONIZED OK
2016-Oct-23 07:13:00.252292 [P2P2]WARNING: no two valid MoneroPulse DNS checkpoint records were received
2016-Oct-23 07:46:18.650151 [P2P6][89.123.45.67:18080 OUT]Sync data returned unknown top block: 1163525 -> 227082 [936443 blocks (756 days) ahead] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2016-Oct-23 08:16:10.241713 [P2P0]WARNING: no two valid MoneroPulse DNS checkpoint records were received
2016-Oct-23 08:16:14.973720 [P2P6][234.56.78.90:18080 OUT]Sync data returned unknown top block: 1163542 -> 1134708 [28834 blocks (40 days) ahead] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2016-Oct-23 08:16:17.184723 [P2P6][234.56.78.90:18080 OUT] SYNCHRONIZED OK
2016-Oct-23 08:16:52.855773 [P2P6][76.54.32.109:18080 OUT]Sync data returned unknown top block: 1163542 -> 89742 [1073800 blocks (851 days) ahead] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2016-Oct-23 09:18:35.376071 [P2P2][111.222.33.44:18080 OUT]Sync data returned unknown top block: 1163582 -> 1009827 [153755 blocks (213 days) ahead] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2016-Oct-23 09:19:53.890182 [P2P1][109.87.65.43:18080 OUT]Sync data returned unknown top block: 1163584 -> 211310 [952274 blocks (767 days) ahead] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2016-Oct-23 09:20:21.270223 [P2P9]WARNING: no two valid MoneroPulse DNS checkpoint records were received
2016-Oct-23 09:20:24.152227 [P2P9][222.111.0.99:18080 OUT]Sync data returned unknown top block: 1163585 -> 1148462 [15123 blocks (21 days) ahead] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2016-Oct-23 09:20:26.717231 [P2P6][222.111.0.99:18080 OUT] SYNCHRONIZED OK
2016-Oct-23 09:20:29.281235 [P2P9][56.78.90.123:18080 OUT]Sync data returned unknown top block: 1163585 -> 399859 [763726 blocks (636 days) ahead] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2016-Oct-23 09:22:34.896279 [P2P9][222.111.0.99:18080 OUT] SYNCHRONIZED OK
```

According to [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1854/what-is-the-best-way-to-pop-the-top-block-from-the-monero-blockchain-and-fix-a-b), this is not my problem; it just means that a peer has a different top block. It might be running behind, or it might be on a forked chain.

Usually this is not a problem. The 'status' command will return that I reached the top block on my chain. But shortly after the latest hard fork I did end up on the wrong chain. I made payments that didn't arrive and were not recorded on the valid chain. How can I find more reliable peers? Or fewer unreliable peers, to be precise. I have a long peer list, and always 8+0 connections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a partially synced chain does not mean unreliability. It might be that these nodes are syncing the chain, as you presumably did at some point too. Banning these nodes would mean noone can start using Monero, and would cause the network to die off from attrition.

In order to get incoming connections (currently none, as the 8+0 shows), you need to allow port 18080 through your router, to connect to the machine running the daemon. Firewalls and such must also allow this port. You will then get more peers (and thus a higher likelihood to get one that's got a full chain).